FFMpegCore .Net cuts off the fist few (~1.5) seconds of audio
I want to use FFMpegCore to convert some audio files to raw pcm. I noticed that this always cuts off ~1.5 seconds of my audio from the start. I check my input stream, saved it to HD all good. If use it from cli with the same arguments everything seem fine. I tried -ss 0, no luck. This behavior is observed with .wav (RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz), same issue with different sample rate. I tested mp3 works fine.
public async Task<MemoryStream> ConvertToPcmStreamAsync(Stream inputStream)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    
    var audioInput = new StreamPipeSource(inputStream);
    var audioOutput = new StreamPipeSink(outputStream);

    await FFMpegArguments
        .FromPipeInput(audioInput)
        .OutputToPipe(audioOutput, options => options
            .WithCustomArgument("-ss 0 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1"))
        .ProcessAsynchronously();

    // Reset the position of the memory stream to the beginning
    outputStream.Position = 0;

    return outputStream;
}

